# Jquery function in while loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm new in Jquery and have to display multiple JQuery sliders in one page.

I have to display a slider every time a result comes from a MySQL requests.
I can display one slider, but can't display multiple sliders, because I can't change the name of the ID in javascript.
I'm also not able to call this function multiple times... Please help.

HTML page:

```
<?php
$reponse = $bdd->prepare('SELECT id FROM TABLE WHERE deleted = 0 ');               
$reponse->execute(); 

    $slider = array();
    $i = 0;

    while ($data = $reponse->fetch()) { 

          $slider[$i] = $data['id'];
          $i ++; ?>
          <div id="<?php echo "slider" . $data['id']; ?>"> </div> 
          <input type="text" id="<?php echo "amount" . $data['id']; ?>"> <?php
    } ?>
```

Javascript page:

```
$(function() {
 var name = "#slider1";
    $( name ).slider({
      value:100,
      min: 5,
      max: 300,
      step: 5,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value);
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( $( name ).slider( "value" ));
  });
```

//EDIT

Slider is joined with class to all elements, but I can't put the right value of the slidebar into `amount`.
I have several options to take the ID of current slider moving, but none of them work:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".slider" ).slider({
      value:100,
      min: 5,
      max: 300,
      step: 5,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        // check the event and ui variables to see what the exact reference you
        // your element is but it looks like it's ui.handle
        // console.log(ui);
        // console.log(ui.handle);
        var clicked_element = ui.handle.data('id');
        $( "#amount" + clicked_element ).val( ui.value);
      }
    });
    $( "#amount3" ).val( $( ".slider" ).slider( "value" ));
  });
```

Comment: What does the value of `ui.handle.data('id')` give you? Note that the last line of your code will not work, you need to loop over all `.slider` elements and put the correct value in the correct `#amount` box.

Comment: `undefined is not a function`, that's the only thing I can see. I know about the last line. Looping works, but trying to get the last ID in this loop

Comment: And what is the result of `console.log(ui.handle);`? Do you have a test-page online?

Comment: I see this line appearing everytime I move a mm f the slidebar: `<span class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" tabindex="0" style="left: 33.8983050847458%;"></span>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can try this code :)

Html

```
<div id="slider1"></div> 
<div id="slider3"></div> 
<div id="slider4"></div> 
<div id="slider6"></div> 
<div id="slider8"></div>
```

jQuery.

```
for(var i = 0; i< count; i++){
    (function(i){
        var name = "#slider" + i;
       if($(name)){
        $( name ).slider({
            value:100,
            min: 5,
            max: 300,
            step: 5,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value);
            }
        });
       }
    })(i);
}
```

in code **count** is count of tag **div** **id=slider+i**

update

```
 <?php
$reponse = $bdd->prepare('SELECT id FROM TABLE WHERE deleted = 0 ');               
$reponse->execute();

$slider = array();
$i = 0;

while ($data = $reponse->fetch()) { 

      $slider[$i] = $data['id'];
      $i ++; ?>
      <div id="<?php echo "slider" . $data['id']; ?>"> </div> 
      <input type="text" id="<?php echo "amount" . $data['id']; ?>"> <?php
} 
echo "<script> var count = $i;</script>";
?>
```

I have added  `echo "<script> var count = $i;</script>";` this code had been declare val of count;

Comment: Problem is that I have : <div id="slider1"></div>, <div id="slider3"></div>, <div id="slider4"></div> 
Not ordered. + it don't seems that JQuery function can be in a loop...

Comment: How can I get the last `i` of `id=slider+i`

Answer (score 1):

You should add a class to the elements that you want to attach the sliders to so that you can attach them to all at once:

```
<div id="<?php echo "slider" . $data['id']; ?>" class="my_slider"> </div>
```

And the javascript:

```
 // attach slider to all elements at once
 $('.my_slider').slider({
    value:100,
    ...
```

Then you have several options to get the right amount box:

- You can get the next element in the DOM. The disadvantage is that this depends on the structure of the html. For example: `$(this).next()`;
- You can add a data attribute to get the correct ID and you can use that to target the correct amount;
- You can wrap the combinations of sliders and amounts in a container element so that you can easily target the correct amount. This is a bit more flexible than the first option as the elements don't have to be next to each other.

Note that you will have to check if `$(this)` inside your inner function still contains a reference to the manipulated slider `div`. The documentation should clear that up.

**Edit:** Some more information about the second option:

html / php:

```
<div class="my_slider" data-id="<?php echo $data['id']; ?>"> </div>
<input type="text" id="<?php echo "amount" . $data['id']; ?>">
```

javascript:

```
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        // check the event and ui variables to see what the exact reference you
        // your element is but it looks like it's ui.handle
        // console.log(ui);
        // console.log(ui.handle);
        var clicked_element = ui.handle.data('id');
        $( "#amount" + clicked_element ).val( ui.value);
      }
```

Comment: This seems much easier with a class! But I always need to put the value of the slider in the right `amount` div.
Option 2 is the way I wan't to do it, but how to pass the id into the function?

Comment: @gr3g I have added a simple example but you would have to check how you can access the manipulated slider exactly. It looks like it is `ui.handle`.

Comment: When trying ui.handle I have `undentified is not a function` when moving the slider. With other tries I have the number in my javascript console...

Comment: @gr3g It sounds like your 99% there. If you are still stuck you should put the edited code and the results from the console below your original question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" /> 

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../search/jquery-ui.structure.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../search/jquery-ui.theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Jqueryslider/jquery-ui.min.css">

    </head>
 <body> 
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="Jqueryslider/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>  
 <script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js"> </script>

<?php

MYSQL QUERY

while(fetch)
{
<div id="<?php echo "slider" . $data['id']; ?>"> </div> 
<input type="text" id="<?php echo "amount" . $data['id']; ?>">

     <script type="text/javascript">
                initSlider("<?php echo $data['id'];?>");
     </script>
}

?>
 </body>
 </html
```

myfile.js

```
function initSlider(i){
        var name = "#slider"+i;
       if($(name)){
        $( name ).slider({
            value:100,
            min: 5,
            max: 300,
            step: 5,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#amount"+i ).val( ui.value);
            }
        });
       $( "#amount"+i ).val( $( "#slider" + i ).slider( "value" ));
       }
    }
```